# Blender Hangs Using Intel Integrated Graphics

Tags: graphics, intel-graphics, blender

Blender frequently hangs and has to be killed during normal use of edit mode and object mode with Intel integrated graphics. I am using version 3.6.0 on Ubuntu 22.04, though the issue is present in other versions. I have had this problem for as long as I have had Ubuntu installed, and it persisted through an Ubuntu reinstall. I was able to find the following in Logs after a freeze:

Under "system"

```
20:02:34 kernel: i915 0000:00:02.0: [drm] GPU HANG: ecode 9:1:85df9e9f, in blender [35275]
20:02:34 kernel: i915 0000:00:02.0: [drm] blender[35275] context reset due to GPU hang
```

Under "applications"

```
20:02:26 blender: WAYLAND found but libdecor was not, install libdecor for Wayland support, falling back to X11
20:02:26 blender: Unable to find 'libdecor-0.so'
```

The freezes appear to go away if I use a rather antiquated external graphics card (which is worse in every other use case), so the issue seems specific to the Intel graphics. No other program appears to have problems with it. I've searched around a good bit, but there's a >50% chance I'm missing something painfully obvious. Thank you!

EDIT: Installing libdecor has no influence on the hangs, so the first log messages are the only relevant ones.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I also got hit by this problem on Debian 11 ("Bullseye") with Blender 3.6.1 (official Linux binary). Blender gets unresponsive simply by resizing the startup cube! `dmesg` shows similar messages about GPU hang. My graphic card is Skylake GT2 [HD Graphics 520] integrated along a Intel Core i5-6300U.

I've found this problem reported as issue [2935](https://gitlab.freedesktop.org/drm/intel/-/issues/2935) (and duplicate [3125](https://gitlab.freedesktop.org/drm/intel/-/issues/3125)) on Freedesktop repo for Intel drm/i915 kernel driver.

I've tried Petr Nosek's workaround mentioned in these discussions:

First, increase the driver parameter `preempt_timeout_ms` to 10000. That change can be done with any text editor (with root permission), but here is a one line command that does the job (using `tee` as explained by https://stackoverflow.com/a/36853636):

```
$ echo 10000 | sudo tee /sys/class/drm/card0/engine/rcs0/preempt_timeout_ms
```

The change can be checked by `$ cat /sys/class/drm/card0/engine/rcs0/preempt_timeout_ms`.

Remark: this driver setting change is *not persistent across reboots!*

Then, Blender should be launched with an environment variable (no clue what it does, but it's documented at https://docs.mesa3d.org/envvars.html#intel-driver-environment-variables).

```
$ INTEL_DEBUG=reemit blender
```

However, I found this second step easier to automate by modifying the `blender.desktop` launcher file I had placed in `~/.local/share/applications`. Following https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/469466/194642, I've modified the Exec line to be:

```
Exec=env INTEL_DEBUG=reemit /my/path/to/blender/bin/blender-3.6.1/blender %f
```

So far it works (no more Blender freeze)...

Comment: Excellent! This seems to fix it. Thank you very much!

Comment: In the mean time, I've updated to Debian 12 "bookworm" with kernel 6.1 (compared to 5.10 in bullseye) and the workaround is still needed.